# Midpoint method for fourth order equation

Tags: python, math, ode, solver

Im trying to solve a fourth order ODE using the midpoint method.

The system of equations is:

```
system = @(t,z)[z(2);

    (c*z(2) + (k/a)*(exp(a*(z(1) + l*sin(z(3)))) - 1 + exp(a*(z(1) - ...
    l*sin(z(3)))) - 1) ...
    + 0.2*m*v*sin(w*t))/-m;

    z(4);

    -c/m*z(4) - 3/m/l*cos(z(3)) * k/a*(exp(a*(z(1) + l*sin(z(3))))...
    - exp(a*(z(1) - l*sin(z(3)))))];
```

or in form of
[mathematical formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78Otd.png).

the constants are:

```
m = 2500;
k = 1000;
a = 0.2;
l = 6;
c = 25;
w = 1.2*pi;
v = 50;
```

the method needs to be repeated until t = 1000.

Does anyone know of a function that could solve this using the mid-point method in Matlab or Python?

Comment: As the midpoint method is a little less stable than the trapezoidal method, you will not find it in standard libraries. You have to code it yourselft. Is that the explicit or the implicit method?

Comment: I am looking for the explicit method. Is there a basic structure/good resource I could use to help code this?

Comment: Then you just have to repeatedly compute `z[k+1] = system(t[k]+dt/2, z[k]+system(t[k],z[k])*dt/2)`, there is nothing deep about it. Do not forget to test your code against an ODE where you know the exact solution, there is nothing that can go wrong with the method step itself, but one has to be careful in designing the loop around it.